# Convert json with key dynamic to POJO.. java spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I need to convert the json into a pojo I already have the service that consumes it but I want to take it to a POJO to be able to handle it

this is  all Json:

```
{
"meta": {
"status": "success",
"version": "2.0"
},
"data": {
"id": "M!t!Ch!v1!0000100002-5gda5bq0059b1-1245432868",
"token": "d71b160d82dfeeca87aa580f526d8570",
"privileges": {
  "__GLOBAL__": {
    "Store": {
      "1-m!i!s-045-158": {
        "*": -1
      },
      "1-m!i!s-047-324": {
        "*": -1
      },
      "1-m!i!s-031-1491": {
        "*": -1
      },
      "1-m!i!s-046-2": {
        "*": -1
      }
    }
  }
 },
"data": {
   "accessorId": 100001
 }
 }
 }
```

this part all keys is dinamic:

```
"1-m!i!s-045-158":{"*":-1} // **the key: 1-m!i!s-045-158 is dinamic** 
{"1-m!i!s-045-158":{"*":-1},"1-m!i!s-047-324":{"*":-1},"1-m!i!s-031-1491":{"*":-1},"1-m!i!s-046-2":{"*":-1}}
```

this is my controller

```
    public JsonNode Evento(JsonNode json) {


    HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
    //header.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
    JsonNode node = mapper.convertValue(json  , JsonNode.class);
    HttpEntity<?> request = new HttpEntity<>(node);
    JsonNode resultado = template.postForObject("http://localhost:8083/moddo-channels/api/miinto", request, JsonNode.class);


    System.out.println(json.findPath("stote"));
    System.out.println(resultado);

    return json;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must write POJO with all fields,

```
private Meta meta;
```

and

```
public class Meta{
   private String status;
   private String version;
}
```

etc in this style, problem can was with Store - it's must be Map

After this, you can take Jackson ObjectMapper and read object from your response

Comment: yes i know that i can make a POJO From other json, but this have dinamic keys in store. i am confuse with this part.

Comment: good, Store is HashMap<String, CustomObject> where class CustomObject{ @JsonProperties("*") private int star;}